# Best Practice to Store API tokens

Tags: json, powershell, security, encryption, cryptography

I am working with an API for automating tasks in a company I work for.

The software will run from a single server and there will only one instance of the sensitive data.

I have a tool that our team uses at the end of every day.

The token only needs to be requested once since it has a +-30 minute timeout.

Since I work with Salesforce API, the user has to enter his/her password either way since it relates the ticket to their account.

The API `oAuth2` tokens and all of its sensitive components need to be secured.

I use PowerShell & a module called `FileCryptograhy` to produce an `AES` version of my `config.json`.

In my config file, I store all the component keys that need to be used to generate the token itself.

**Steps**

---

1. `Base64` encode strings
2. Use `FileCyptography` module to encrypt the `JSON` file with a secret key into an `AES` file.
3. When API needs to produce a token, it works in reverse to get all the data.

---

Is this a valid way of securing sensitive API data, or is there a more efficient way?

P.S: I understand that nothing is very secure and can be reverse engineered, I just need something that will keep at least 90% of people away from this data.

Comment: There is no point in throwing cryptography at stuff without first defining your threat model.  What do you actually want to protect against?

Comment: I want to secure plaintext data from not only users but potentially if the server is breached, from the breachers themselves.

Comment: Well, the code to decrypt the tokens is on the server and the attackers have access to the server... Fill in the blanks? :)

Comment: The code to decrypt the tokens is there, correct, but the `AES` also requires a plaintext password and a hash, which only our team members know. (:

Comment: So are you going to enter that password everytime your API produces a token?

Comment: Yes but before the token not after. I'll explain briefly not to confuse you. I have a tool that our team uses at the end of every day. The token only needs to be requested once since it has a +-30 minute timeout. Since I work with Salesforce API, the user has to enter his/her password either way since it relates the ticket to their account.

Comment: Okay, you should have added that to your question, it is relevant information. But if that is the case, provided you implement the encryption properly, then the security comes down to your password management.

Comment: I am also trying to leave out the password stage and maybe use some kind of certificate instead, I've seen somewhere that you can use Powershell to generate user profile crets to decrypt information. Would you know anything about certificates?

Comment: x509 is mainly for asymmetric cryptography, so while you could use certificates here it will increase the complexity of what you're doing greatly when you don't really need public key crypto.

Comment: So I guess I should stick to requesting the password instead? I've used x.509 a few times before when I was working on college projects but I never really understood them to be fully comfortable with them.

Comment: To be honest, you should use an existing tool that was designed for your situation.  Implementing cryptography yourself when you don't have a full and complete understanding of what is happening is generally a poor idea!

Comment: Thanks, @LukeJoshuaPark, You really helped out here. Post an answer and I'll vote for best answer.